# Sleep() Methods and OS - Scheduler (Camunda/Groovy)

Tags: groovy, scripting, operating-system, scheduler, camunda

I got a question for you guys and its not as specific as usual, which could make it a little annoying to answer.

The tool i'm working with is Camunda in combination with Groovy scripts and the goal is to reduce the maximum cpu load (or peak load). I'm doing this by "stretching" the work load over a certain time frame since the platform seems to be unhappy with huge work load inputs in a short amount of time. The resulting problem is that Camunda wont react smoothly when someone tries to operate it at the UI - Level.

So i wrote a small script which basically just lets each individual process determine his own "time to sleep" before running, if a certain threshold is exceeded. This is based on how many processes are trying to run at the same time as the individual process.

It looks like:

Process wants to start -> Process asks how many other processes are running ->
waitingTime = numberOfProcesses * timeToSleep * iterationOfMeasures

[CPU-Usage Curve 1,3 without the Script. Curve 2,4 With the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNg2A.png)

Testing it i saw that i could stretch the work load and smoothe out the UI - Levels. But now i need to describe why this is working exactly.

The Questions are:

1. What does a sleep method do exactly ?
2. What does the sleep method do on CPU - Level?
3. How does an OS-Scheduler react to a Sleep Method?
4. Namely: Does the scheduler reschedule or just simply "wait" for the time given?
5. How can i recreate and test the question given above?

The main goal is not for you to answer this, but could you give me a hint for finding the right Literature to answer these questions? Maybe you remember a book which helped you understand this kind of things or a Professor recommended something to you. (Mine wont answer, and i cant blame him)

I'm grateful for hints and or recommendations !

Answer (score 0):

i'm sure you could use timer event

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.15/reference/bpmn20/events/timer-events/

it allows to postpone next task trigger for some time defined by expression.

---

about sleep in java/groovy: https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/sleep.shtml

using sleep is blocking current thread in groovy/java/camunda.

so instead of doing something effective it's just blocked.

Comment: First of all Thanks for your answer ! *repost cause i couldnt edit*

The Timer Event doesnt work out for various reasons:

- it doesnt hold enough runtime configuration mechanisms for my purpose
- I would have to touch every process if i wanted to make a major change in waiting times/ waiting time calculations
- I want to listen to the whole platform for processes in work, not only a specific scope
- there are some more issues which simply would take too long to explain 

The link for the thread sleep is a great hint, thanks!